# jQuery how to use DOM objects from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following source tree:

```
source
|-html
|  |-div1.html
|  |_div2.html
|-js
|  |_bundle.js
|_index.html
```

And my `index.html` looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#div1').load('./html/div1.html');
      });
      $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#div2').load('./html/div2.html');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I use jQuery such that I can manipulate `<div>` in the external html sources of `div1.html` and `div2.html`? Assuming that both of them contain the following code segment:

```
<div id="tParagraph">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#div1 #tParagraph') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should note is id's must be unique as you saying both files have same HTML.

And once you loaded successfully, you can access those elements like any other DOM elements.

```
$("#tParagraph")
```

And  inorder to make sure that it loaded, you must use a callback.

```
 $('#div2').load('./html/div2.html', function(){

  // loaded.
});
```

putting it all together

```
$('#div2').load('./html/div2.html', function(){
   $("#tParagraph").dosomeThing();
});
```